# Update ifstream object after data is written to its file using ofstream

Tags: c++, fstream

While testing my code, I faced an issue, that `ifstream` doesn't get updated when more data is written to its file. So here is a sample code that demonstrates the problem:

```
    ifstream is(filename);
    string line;
    while (getline(is, line))
        cout << "line: " << line << endl;

    ofstream os(filename, ofstream::out | ofstream::app);
    string additional("additional");
    os << additional;
    os.flush();

    while (getline(is, line))
        cout << "line additional: " << line << endl;
```

No additional lines were written to `stdout`, though they are written to the file.
I'm not using `fstream` instead of a couple of if/ofstream because I need it like this for testing purposes.

How to make `ifstream` "see" the changes in the file?

**UPDATE**: I cleared the bits using `clear` method. It works OK on my Ubuntu machine with gcc. But it doesn't work on my Mac OSX with llvm. Do you know how to do it platform independently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `std::ios::clear` on the input stream after the first read.
When you read the whole file, it sets the failbit in the stream and will refuse to keep reading, even if the file actually changed in the meantime.

```
ifstream is(filename);
string line;
while (getline(is, line))
    cout << "line: " << line << endl;

ofstream os(filename, ofstream::out | ofstream::app);
string additional("additional");
os << additional;
os.flush();

is.clear(); //< Now we can read again
while (getline(is, line))
    cout << "line additional: " << line << endl;
```

Comment: Oops you're absolutely right, I've edited the answer, thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I got eofbit and failbit set, so basically it doesn't matter, I just clear it and it works Ok on ubuntu, gcc. Though it doesn't work on Mac OSX, llvm. Any ideas why? Unfortunately I can't use lldb to debug it on Mac.

Answer (score 2):

When you hit the end of the file while reading `is` the first time, it sets the `eofbit` in the stream's internal error state.

You need to clear it before you can continuing reading, by calling the `is.clear()` function, which resets the internal error state.

Comment: Close but `eofbit` is not the bit that causes the problem, it's `failbit`. But your answer is correct otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that you have opened output stream file using "ofstream::out"

```
ofstream os(filename, ofstream::out | ofstream::app);
```

now, the "ofstream::out" truncates the file as soon as it opens it. That is, all the previous contents of your file will be deleted once it is opened. Please try using this instead:

```
ofstream os(filename, ios::app);
```

Comment: `std::ios_base::out` is always used regardless of whether it is specified as an openmode. `std::ios_base::app` disables the contents from being destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS `clear()` and `sync()`. Append the file in parallel to watch it work.

```
    std::ifstream ifs(filename);
    std::string line;

    while (run) {
        if (!ifs)
            std::cout << "ifs not open\n";

        while (std::getline(ifs, line)) 
            std::cout << line << "\n";
        ifs.clear();
        ifs.sync()
        
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    }
```

xref: Howard Hinnant [Ifstream not seeing new content on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810779/ifstream-not-seeing-new-content-on-osx)