# Ifstream not seeing new content on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, file-io

I'm currently attempting to read an ifstream, that another process is writing to, and then sending it to my standard out stream. The file can be quite large so I'm hoping to do everything I can to not have to re-read the whole stream. To do this I've been opening an ifstream, and calling "clear" to remove the EoF bit.

On our linux hosts this is working fine (Arch, Debian, Ubuntu), however in our tested versions of OSX this does not work.

I created the smallest possible test file I could to test this:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

int main() {
  auto temp_to_close = std::ofstream { std::string("stdout") };
  temp_to_close.close();

  auto stdout_stream = std::ifstream(std::string("stdout"));

  while (true) {
    stdout_stream.clear();
    std::cout << "--------------------------------------------" << "\n";
    std::cout << "EOF Stdout: " << (stdout_stream.eof() ? "T" : "F") << "\n";
    std::cout << "Fail Stdout: " << (stdout_stream.fail() ? "T" : "F") << "\n";
    std::cout << "--------------------------------------------" << "\n";

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(stdout_stream, line)) {
      std::cout << line << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "[" << (stdout_stream.eof() ? "T" : "F") << (stdout_stream.fail() ? "T" : "F") << "] line: " << line << "\n";
    std::cout.flush();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  }

  return 0;
}
```

On both Mac, and Linux this is the process we follow:

```sh
$ clang++ main.cpp -std=c++17 -Wall -o a.out
$ ./a.out
$ #open a new terminal window, cd to the same directory.
$ #next type: "echo "hello" >> stdout"
$ #switch back to the main window
```

On linux this does end up printing the: "hello" among the other output:

```
--------------------------------------------
EOF Stdout: F
Fail Stdout: F
--------------------------------------------
hello
[TT] line:
```

Which is what we expect. On Mac however we just get:

```
--------------------------------------------
EOF Stdout: F
Fail Stdout: F
--------------------------------------------
[TT] line:
```

OSX Version Info:

```
Mac OSX: v10.14.5
XCode Version: v10.2.1 (10E1001)
Clang++ --version:
Apple LLVM Version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x85_64-apple-darwin-18.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

---

*EDIT* as mentioned by Eljay in the comments. Adding a seekg gets all platforms to see the content:

```cpp
stdout_stream.clear();
stdout_stream.seekg(stdout_stream.tellg());
```

Comment: I added `stdout_stream.seekg(stdout_stream.tellg());` after the `stdout_stream.clear();`, and then it is seeing the new data.  Not sure if this is all in the realm of platform specific behavior.

Comment: Yep, that totally worked across linux, and our mac devices. Not sure why it was needed, but :shrug:

Comment: The `seekg` must do a `sync`.  Howard for the win!

Answer (score 3):

After you `clear()` `stdout_stream`, also `sync()` it:

```
stdout_stream.sync();
```

This is a specific request to flush any underlying stream buffer.