# Using temporary files for working with large amount of data

Tags: c++, multithreading, fstream

I am trying to implement interthread communication using a temporary serialized file (pointer table containing [no, offset, length] in data file and data file containing data). One thread should receive data (process it) and save it to memory. The second thread should read data from memory and display results. (The input thread is only appending data and the output thread is only reading.)

I must compile it as 32-bit, so I try to solve the 2 GB limit by reading/writing a temporary file.

I have implemented a simple example. But the problem is, that if I/O threads are working simultaneously, then the output thread does not read properly. If the input thread writes and closes the file, then the output thread reads and closes it works fine. I have done synchronization with shared_mutex and mutex with the same bad results.

Thank you in advance for your responses.

**UPDATE:** Behavior gets better by resetting flags (stream.clear()) according to [Update ifstream object after data is written to its file using ofstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807245/update-ifstream-object-after-data-is-written-to-its-file-using-ofstream) but still sometimes it fails and sometimes pass.

Main:

```
int main() {        
      //Start input and output job
      std::thread input = std::thread(inputJob);
      std::thread output = std::thread(outputJob);
        
      //Wait here for end
      input.join();
      output.join();
    
    //HERE checking results
    
      return 0;
}
```

Input job:

```
void inputJob() {
    is_on = true;
    //Loading input data
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        student s("George", "Patton", 100000 + i, (i % 2) > 0, "0A");
        for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) s.subjects.push_back(subject(rand(), "MA", (j % 5)));
        s1.push_back(s);
    }

    //Save to binary file
    std::fstream data_stream, table_stream;
    table_stream.open("./table.data", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc | std::fstream::binary);
    data_stream.open("./data.data", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc | std::fstream::binary);
    size_t off = 0;
    if (table_stream.is_open() && data_stream.is_open()) for (size_t i = 0; i < s1.size(); i++) {
        std::string tmp = s1[i].toBinaryString();
        size_t sz = tmp.size();
        table_row t(i, off, sz);
        off += sz;
        {
            std::lock_guard lock(m);
            table_stream << t.toBinaryString();
            data_stream << tmp;
            cout << "Written" << endl;
        }       
    }
    table_stream.close();
    data_stream.close();
    is_on = false;
}
```

output job:

```
    void outputJob() {
    //Load from binary file
    std::fstream data_stream, table_stream;
    table_stream.open("./table.data", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::binary);
    data_stream.open("./data.data", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::binary);
    if (table_stream.is_open() && data_stream.is_open()) {
        size_t row_sz = sizeof(table_row);
        std::string line = "";
        size_t index = 0;

            unsigned table_r = 0;
            bool was_empty = false;
            while (is_on || (was_empty == false)) {
                {
                    std::lock_guard lock(m);
                    if (tryGetData(table_stream, line, row_sz, table_r) == 0 && line.empty() == false) {
                        table_r += row_sz;
                        was_empty = false;
                        table_row row;
                        index = 0;
                        row.fromBinaryString(line, index, line.size());

                        if (tryGetData(data_stream, line, row.len, row.off) == 0 && line.empty() == false) {
                            was_empty = false;
                            index = 0;
                            student tmp;
                            tmp.fromBinaryString(line, index);
                            if (VAL_CHECK == 1) s2.push_back(tmp);
                        }
                        else was_empty = true;
                    }
                    else was_empty = true;
                }
            }
        
    }
    table_stream.close();
    data_stream.close();
}
```

Try get data function:

```
    int tryGetData(std::fstream &data_stream, std::string& data, size_t data_sz, size_t offset) {
    int ret = 0;
    data = "";
        if (data_stream.is_open()) {
            //Set ptr
            if (offset != UINT32_MAX) data_stream.seekp(offset);

            char c;
            while (data_sz > 0 && data_stream.get(c)) {
                data.push_back(c);
                data_sz--;
            }
            if (data_stream.eof()) ret = 1;
        }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: What about named pipes? Windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipes Linux: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann The problem is, that I need to store all infos from input thread until output thread does not terminate program. F. example input thread saved all students of school to memory and output thread reads user specified students and displays it in GUI. (Like SQL but in my case I do not have to save columns. I can save blocks of memory - I tried to decrease temporary file size.)

Comment: @Ales100 dumb question: have you considered SQLite compiled in multithreaded mode?

Comment: Writing to a stream does not guarantee it is on-disk when the write completes. If the 'outputJob()' function acts more like 'tail -f <file>' then two threads can use a file for IPC. Also, `tryGetData()` is reading one character at a time instead of a using a [block-read](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read). Therefore, I expect `outputJob()` to be slower than `inputJob()`.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Mgetz I know that this problem is solved in many 3rd libraries. But I do not understand why to use 3rd party libs when the desired functionality can be written on 300 lines. I need only serialize string/int/vectors.

Comment: @DanielDearlove If understand it well, then flush() guarantee the buffer is written to disk. Ok, thank you, block read would be probably better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is, that writing thread may start later that reading thread. If reading thread is waiting for opening file by writing thread, then it works like charm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can think of is using double-buffering. Have two of each file type, and make sure the input thread is writing into one pair while the output thread is always reading the other pair.

All other solutions I can think of would require making sure that the OS or the file library is not doing any caching on the file and thus would be platform-specific. But if that's not a problem, read up on [memory mapped files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file), for example.

Comment: While memory mapped files are definitely preferable, they likely won't work here because OP is limited to 32bit address space.

Comment: I  don't see what the problem is with memory mapped files compiled in 32 bit.  I have done it numerous times and they work great.  They benchmark very well against other common inter-process communication schemes in Windows.  One issue is both ends (writer and readers) must understand the exact size and layout of the contents of the file.

Comment: @ttemple Because address space in 32bit is upper-bounded by `2^32 = 4.3GB`. In practice this will even be lower. Consequently, you won't be able to completely map a file greater than 4.3GB, e.g. a dataset of 1TB; correct me if I am wrong. While one can map such big files in an ad-hoc fashion; this results in significantly increased complexity. I'm not saying that memory-mapped files are bad per-se, quite the contrary, but OP explicitely mentioned the 32bit memory cap in his question. On 64bit however, you are basically free to map as much as you want.

Comment: I though he was going to break the dataset into pieces, but it actually say that in his question.  (I find it absurd to attempt to handle 1TB of data at once)