# How to refresh an input file stream in C++

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am writing a program that monitors for changes in a file for a specific purpose. The possible values (3) in the file are known and can be differentiated by the first letter.
Using an input file stream `ifstream status;`, I'm unable to refresh the buffer of the input stream `status` to reflect changes in the file. I don't want to spam `status.close()` and `status.open()` to solve the problem.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/sync

Comment: I got interesting results. I already tried `status.sync()` and it did nothing when I used `status.peek()` to read first letter. But when I used `status.get()` and then `status.seekg(0)` the problem got solved. Apparently `sync()` does nothing in case of `peek()` or `peek()` probably stores its value somewhere independently from the buffer after first read? @AlanBirtles

Comment: Possibly a bug in your standard library? The behaviour of sync isn't specified anywhere so it's difficult to use reliably cross platform

Comment: Thanks for the info, it was compiled using g++ on Fedora 35. I don't intend to use it cross platform since it relies on Linux kernel stuff anyways. @AlanBirtles

Comment: libstdc++ doesn't seem to do anything on [sync](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/0f0b42896196315acfc636b1e535cda4ee283646/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/fstream.tcc#L1013) with the read side

Answer (score 1):

If the changes you mentioned include only appended bytes, then you can use the [`std::ifstream::clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) to clear any error bit and continue reading the file until reaching the `EOF`. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27807411/10400598).

Comment: There is no method `clean` on a stream. Do you mean `clear`?

Comment: Oh, my fault. Thanks for warning me :)